# TypeError: froala_editor__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a is not a constructor

Tags: constructor, frontend, typeerror, froala

I am getting this error. When I am uploading my froala-editor file in 
   the website. Please check the error. Why I am getting this error? I couldn't get any response from froala-editor becuase of this issue. Or do you have any editor in angular

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "froala-editor": "3.0.0-beta.2-1",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.11",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^11.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "^11.1.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^1.1.1",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^16.4.55",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "angular-6-social-login": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-centered": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.5",
    "angular-multiple-select": "^1.1.3",
    "bootstrap-auto-dismiss-alert": "^1.0.2",
    "cookie-signature": "^1.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-picker-directive": "^1.0.15",
    "etag": "^1.8.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "firebase": "^5.10.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.2.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "ngx-ckeditor": "^0.3.2",
    "ngx-ckeditor5": "^1.5.0-12",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-filter-pipe": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-geoautocomplete": "^0.1.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-quill": "^5.0.0",
    "node-modules": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }

}

I m getting the following Error :
```

TypeError: froala_editor__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a is not a constructor

[image: This is error I am getting]

Comment: Please format your code the right way.

Comment: Yes, I have written my code properly.

Comment: TypeError is stil plain text. There is text in existing code block at the end as well. Please fix.

Comment: I have attached the error img plz check